Replace a field with the index of values in an array in JQ
Given the following JSON file:
{
  "quadrants": [
    "Languages + Frameworks",
    "Tools",
    "Platforms",
    "Techniques"
  ],
  "entries": [
    {
      "quadrant": "Languages + Frameworks"
    },
    {
      "quadrant": "Platforms"
    },
    {
      "quadrant": "Languages + Frameworks"
    }
  ]
}

How can the quadrant field of each entry be replaced with the index of the corresponding value in quadrants?
Expected output:
{
  "quadrants": [
    "Languages + Frameworks",
    "Tools",
    "Platforms",
    "Techniques"
  ],
  "entries": [
    {
      "quadrant": 0
    },
    {
      "quadrant": 2
    },
    {
      "quadrant": 0
    }
  ]
}

I tried the following jq script but get null for each quadrant.
jq '
  .entries |= map(
    .quadrant = (.quadrant as $q | (.quadrants | index($q)))
  )
' "$1"


You're looking for something like this:
.quadrants as $l | .entries[].quadrant |= . as $e | $l | index($e)


This works. Thank you, kindly.

You can also use double brackets to find the index:
.quadrants as $q | .entries[].quadrant |= $q[[.]][]

Demo
If items in the quadrants array could occur multiple times, use first($q[[.]][]) instead.
For large inputs with many, potentially expensive searches, you could create a lookup INDEX beforehand, and then efficiently just query that:
(.quadrants | to_entries | INDEX(.value)) as $i | .entries[].quadrant |= $i[.].key

Demo
